# How to cite an online short document with texmaker

Tags: citing

I needed to cite an online short PDF document which only shows some information at the bottom of each page:

[image: Example of page footer]

In which format can this be cited with Latex? Could it be considered as some lecture notes, or I can not cite it because no author name is shown?

Comment: Asking about citation advice with only this amount of information is not a good fit for this site. Answers here will be speculative (or opinion-based) and not really based on sound facts.

Comment: 0° [Welcome to Tex stackexchange!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551) 1° It has nothing to do with texmaker. 2° It is not really relevant to this site. But 3° If you provide a link, some people could accept to give you some hints. Where did you find this document?

Comment: here: http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/~wjh/teaching/Fourier/documents/delta.pdf